# How to model a physical channel using verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, transceiver

I don't have access to high speed transceivers FPGA. So i wish to model the channel of high speed transceivers which is not error free so that i can test my codes if they are working fine or not.
Is there any way to model a physical channel using verilog.

Comment: Why don't you just transmit a good signal and add a random 1 or 0 to see what happens?

Comment: Take a look at Opencores.org > "Communication Controller" and see if there are any projects you can leverage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to simulate bit errors, then you can do that without the complexity of simulating a full transceiver.  Just figure out what distribution you need for your bit errors, and flip bits according to that distribution.

Comment: I am not sure what distributions should i take. I am hoping to simulate bit errors but don't know how to do this. Can you provide with more explanation on how to do that.

Comment: Also i want to see the effect on bit error using different things like equalisation etc., will i be able to do that if i only figure out the distribution.

Comment: Well, a starting point is to just assume the bit errors are uniform random. So pick random numbers between 0 and 1 for each bit, if it's less than, say, 10^-6 or whatever, flip the bit. Try different thresholds for different error rates.

Comment: And how to control these bit errors using different things like equalisation, pre-emphasis etc.

Comment: Have you coded anything like that to simulate the bit error ?